# Installing a tar file, ./configure not working

Tags: tar

Before you flag this as duplicate, its not.

Im trying to install a tar file called phaser-3.3.0.tar.gz

I do the steps that are needed, all works fine until I reach the ./configure step.

I cd into the folder that has been extracted, and use ./configure, I get the error:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Can someone walk me through every single command I need to install the tar file? I think I might be missing something.

Comment: I cd over to the extracted file, so I run it in the folder of the tar file I just extracted.

Comment: What do you mean ls -1? @AliRazmdideh

Comment: Alright, got it,  1 second @AliRazmdideh

Comment: Where do I run it though? In my Downloads folder or in the folder of the tar file  I extracted? @AliRazmdideh

Comment: Ah. Thanks! @dsstorefile following the steps atm.

Comment: @dsstorefile The steps are a bit complex, its asking me to install a bunch of things, Im confused.  Are you able to help me?